# How to create a function that generates a random 3 letter sequence?

Tags: javascript, random

I need to connect the webpage with a 'random.js' file which I hope I have already correctly done, as well as creating a function named 'GenerateSequence' that generates 3 random letters. I have inserted 3 'RandomChar' into the body but am not entirely sure where exactly they go. In the end the page needs to look like this

[image]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
<head>
<meta charset='utf-8'>
 <title>Random Letter Sequence</title>

 <script type="text/javascript" src="random.js"></script>

 <script type="text/javascript">
 function GenerateSequence()
 {

 }
</script>
</head>

<body>
<h2>Generate 3-Letter Sequence</h2>

sequence =  RandomChar('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz') +
        RandomChar('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz') +
        RandomChar('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz');

<hr>
<h3>You Random 3-Letter Sequence<h3>
<div id="outputDiv"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/) SO is not a site where you can just ask for finished code.

Comment: 1) put the script statements inside the function 2) use [Math.random](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random) and 3) insert using [innerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.innerHTML)

Comment: Please consider reading the [Javascript guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide).

Comment: Well I have literally no idea what to do and even given these 3 steps above this comment I am still so lost

Comment: So read the documentation behind the steps I gave. Plenty of examples there

Answer (score 0):

```
function GenerateSequence(){
  var result = "";
  var alphabet = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";

  for(var i=0;i<3;i++){
      result += alphabet.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * alphabet.length));
  }
  return result;
}
window.onload = function(){
  document.getElementById('goButton').onclick=function() {  
    document.getElementById('outputDiv').innerHTML = GenerateSequence();
  }
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1349404/generate-a-string-of-5-random-characters-in-javascript <- Indeed taken from here. :-)

Comment: So why exactly did you copypaste it? What's wrong with a simple link?

Comment: To edit and provide a simple answer for the user.

Comment: This code doesn't work though, I am getting no random sequence generated when I click the Generate button

Comment: No you'd still have to execute the function on a click of a button or div and output the result for the user to see.

Comment: Well besides that this example requires me to include the statement -                                                                 sequence =  RandomChar('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz') +
            RandomChar('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz') +
       RandomChar('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz');                   into the function. How do I do this given what you have provided?

Comment: Execute the function and output the return in to your outputDiv.

Comment: I read what you're writing but its like you're speaking a different language. I don't mean to annoy you but I have no idea what that means . Could you possibly explain in layman's terms? @EmeryFramboise

Comment: See my edit of your answer

Comment: Why exactly did you roll it back? I'm sincerely trying to help.

Comment: I did not roll anything back, I just fixed your poor coding

Comment: Thanks guys I got it to work but rather than having the random sequence load when the page does I need it to appear when a button labeled 'Go!' in the <body> is clicked and generates a new sequence each time clicked

Comment: See update. I could post my own but never mind

Comment: Oh yeah that's better, sorry oversaw the last part and thought it had returned to the original function.

Comment: I have exactly what you've edited up above but it isn't working. Aptana says on the lines begining with 'window.onload' and the line after I'm missing semi colons, yet when I add them I get a syntax error?